# change onClick event of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is the code to change on click event of div,

```
Onclick:   function {  flipIT()},
.
.
.
.
.
.
for()
{
//inside loop
    image.onclick = my.onClick;
}
```

i want to edit my code and change .click into .bind() , i want to use something like,

```
$(image).bind('click touch touchstart ', function () {
   ??? how to assigned my.Onclick here
          }
```

i cant directly write flipIt()  because i have written that inside loop so function will b called many times.

Comment: Rewrite the code for `bind`. Where is the problem?

Comment: @ i want to write something like image.touch=my.onClick???  i need to use binding

Comment: What are you looping through? A more complete example with an explanation of what you're trying to achieve would help you get an answer. I'm trying to think why you would bind anything inside a loop, where you should be able to do it with jQuery selectors

Comment: No need to loop with a jQuery selector. `$('.image')` would access all elements with a class of image and attach the click event. Then run the function `$('.image').bind('click touch touchstart', function(){ flipIT() });`

Comment: @Mark Walters  loop i need beacuse i have made image slider ... on click of image loop execute many times and bring images into center

Comment: Well then you swap the class selector for your variable in the loop, but you still call your flipIT function from within rather than my.Onclick `$(image).bind('click touch touchstart', function(){ flipIT() });`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *re-bind* an event, just unbind then bind again.

`$('#myelem').unbind('click').bind('click', function() { ... });`

Comment: i want to assigned it it another event my.onClick .

Answer (score 0):

Is better to use ON OFF, instead of bind unbind

```
$(image).on('click touch touchstart ', function () {
   $(this).off('click touch touchstart').on('click touch touchstart', function () {
      //new stuff here
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event object into the handling function, and use event.type:

```
$(image).bind('click touch touchstart', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'click') {
    ...
  }
});
```